# How to register Spring WebFilter only for certain paths in webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

How can I tell Spring in `webflux` context to apply a `WebFilter` only on certain

```
@Component
public class RequestIdFilter implements org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        //my logic
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }


//if it was NOT WebFlux, then I would have done so:
@Configuration
class FilterConfig {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestIdFilter> requestIdFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<RequestIdFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new RequestIdFilter());
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns(...);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a workaround you can get the path from `exchange.getRequest().getPath();` And create a `List<PathPattern> pathPatternList;` that contains your paths. And in filter create an if statement, for checking whether to apply filter. Unfortunately not the nicest solution, and probably you also thought about it.

Comment: Yes indeed I would try to avoid implementing my own "path filter", if possible.